# Really get all cookies with chrome.cookies.getAll?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I need to get all cookies (at least in the current CookieStore). First pass, I use

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function (cookies) {
    chrome.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function (changeInfo) {
        // do stuff with added/removed cookies here ...
    };

    // do stuff with all the original cookies here ...
});
```

But now I'm thinking there may be a flaw here: the getAll call asks the browser to list all the existing cookies. The browser then calls the getAll callback with an array of these existing cookies. The extension then registers to get updates for any added/removed/changed cookies. It appears that any cookie which is added by the browser after it creates the cookies array (e.g. via active tabs), but before the addListener call executes, will be lost until updated.

Does anyone have suggestions on a better approach?

I started looking through the chrome dev tools source for examples, but it appears the Resources > Cookies table does not use this API.